# How underscored directories are filtered in Jekyll/Webrick?

Tags: server, jekyll, webrick

#### Update: Check my answer below.

---

I just realized that in Jekyll Webrick server, directories starting with *underscores(_includes, _layouts etc.)* can't be accessed and are not listed when `jekyll serve --show-dir-listing` option is turned on. I wonder how Jekyll does that, as Webricks shows underscored directories on default. I did a quick search in the [source code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll), I checked `lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb` and similar files, but could not find the exact reason. It might be something related to *fancy_listing*?

Example:
[image]
It is there!:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found the relevant code in `jekyll/reader.rb`, which has a *filter* function and it is defined in `jekyll/entry_filter.rb`! :) Here is the code:

- First a regex is defined:

```rb
 SPECIAL_LEADING_CHAR_REGEX = %r!\A#{Regexp.union([".", "_", "#", "~"])}!o.freeze
```

- Then `special?`function is defined:

```rb
def special?(entry)
  SPECIAL_LEADING_CHAR_REGEX.match?(entry) ||
      SPECIAL_LEADING_CHAR_REGEX.match?(File.basename(entry))
end
```

- And `special?`function is used in the filter function to detect and filter those files matching the regex.
- And the `Reader`class is using this filtering function in various places.

  To be honest, I still did not get how jekyll bring those things together but I think I'll try to figure them out myself.